# How to get QR Code for the on going app development

Tags: android, google-apps

I am developing an an android app for google play store for a client. My client wants to print a QR Code of the app on the product, to enable user to directly download app by scanning this QR code.

How can i give the QR Code for my client while the app is under development.

Any suggestions...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to upload the app to the Play Store for you to get a link to the Play Store.

If your client is just trying to get prepped for the release, the link would be https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.unique.package.name

Just be sure that your package name is not already taken.